# Blank screen after upgrade to 22.04 LTS

Tags: boot, unity, upgrade, 22.04

I recently upgraded from 18.04 to 22.04, and haven't been able to boot to the gui since. Instead, I get a black screen with a blinking cursor in the top left. The servers I have running on the computer are chugging along doing their thing, but I can't get a desktop environment for anything.
I've tried all the relevant solutions I could find on here, including

- reinstalling/reconfiguring gdm3
- reinstalling the unity desktop environment
- editing the command in grub for no splash, and radeon-specific options

and several others that I'm not recalling now. None worked.

Answer (score 1):

From time to time I have had similar problems because of the [nvidia drivers, either by loading an incomplete driver or a driver version which is not compatible](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-nvidia-drivers-ubuntu) if you have a nvidia GPU.  If you have a radeon, might want to follow the same process for a r[adeon specific driver](https://linuxconfig.org/amd-radeon-ubuntu-20-04-driver-installation).  I have had to go down in driver #'s to a more compatible version in the past.

Open Terminal with ctrl-alt-t or ctrl-alt-F1 and try the following:

```
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt -y upgrade
```

which should update the AMD Radeon drivers.  If it is not working, try downgrading

```
$ sudo apt install ppa-purge
$ sudo ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
```

If something was borked during the install, its possible you might have to start the install over, but I would try this first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The first part did its thing without errors, but didn't solve the issue. The ppa-purge command complained `Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: oibaf graphics-drivers`, and also didn't solve it. :-/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after upgrading from 20.04 to 22.04, my problem was because of amdgpu drivers, I managed to solve it by removing amdgpu by using amdgpu-uninstall from a terminal ( CTRL + ALT + F2 ) after that I get the new amdgpu drivers for 22.04

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a GPU for the display? I had the same issue but I have been using a 3090 GPU for the display. If it is same for you, try reinstall the nvidia-driver, you can find the correct version of your nvidia driver from https://www.nvidia.com/download/index.aspx and then login from another machine and run apt install nvidia-driver-xxx where xxx is your driver version, then sudo reboot